# Why is document not defined in Electron renderer.js file?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am creating a desktop app with Electron. I am trying to run a Python script when I click a button (made from HTML) on the app. I did this by using `child_process` and `spawn`. However, when I run `npm start` with command prompt (Windows 10) in the directory, I am getting that `document is not defined` from `renderer.js`.

I know there is something about using `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer` in Electron but I am not sure how to use that. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my folder tree:

```
.
├── hello.py
├── index.html
├── main.js
├── node_modules
│       // node modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── renderer.js
└── require.js
```

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="require.js"></script>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="require.js"></script>
        <button id="push_me" type="button">Push me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

`main.js`:

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
require('./renderer.js');

let win;

function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600, webPrefences: {nodeIntegration: true}});
    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }))

    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null;
    })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
})
```

`renderer.js`:

```js
var pushMe = document.getElementById('push_me');
pushMe.addEventListener('click', runPython());

function runPython() {
    var python = require(['child_process']).spawn('python', ['hello.py']);
    python.stdout.on('data', function(data) { console.log(data.toString('utf8')); });
}
```

`hello.py`:

```py
print("Hello, world!")
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "app_ui",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^8.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "python-shell": "^1.0.8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access `document` from the main process. This is wrong. You can only access DOM APIs inside renderer processes. I recommend reading the [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#main-and-renderer-processes) to know the differences between main and renderer processes.

Your index.html should look like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="require.js"></script>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="require.js"></script>
        <button id="push_me" type="button">Push me</button>
        <script src="renderer.js"></script> <!-- load renderer.js here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

and you should remove `require('./renderer.js');` from main.js